# @fontface custom font not loading in Gatsby

Tags: css, fonts, gatsby, custom-font

my custom font is not working, unless I install it manually in my computer.

```
//my css file//

  @font-face {
  font-family:'PROGRESS PERSONAL USE';
  src: url('Progress.woff2')format('woff2'),
  url('Progress.woff')format('woff'),
  url('Progress.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

Font family name is correct because, I opened the file font to check the correct spelling and also it shows correctly in the browser if I install the font and use it as:

```
h1{
font-family: "PROGRESS PERSONAL USE"
}
```

I thought that the problem was the path of the font files, so I placed them in the same folder and level as the CSS file. I also tried adding a `/` to the path like `url('/Progress.woff2')format('woff2')...` in front. Cleared caché, changed browser, and tried in mobile But not working.
Also in my browser inspector/Network shows that the fonts are found when refreshing the browser:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/Progress.woff2
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Would be happy to get help with this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The self-hosted fonts in Gatsby should be located in the static folder.
So I placed the files in the path:

```
--> static/fonts/Progress.woff2
-->static/fonts/Progress.woff
-->static/fonts/Progress.ttf
```

and then in my globalStyles.css which is in my src/ (not in the static folder) I place it like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family:"PROGRESS PERSONAL USE";
  src: url('/fonts/Progress.woff2')format('woff2'),
  url('/fonts/Progress.woff')format('woff'),
  url('/fonts/Progress.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

If you don't have a global css file you can define one for the fonts, and import it in your gatsby-browser.js.

Also there is the option of using the web fonts gatsby pluggin  which is explained [here](https://medium.com/@igloude/4-steps-to-self-hosted-fonts-in-gatsby-d40db29e57c2)